# How can I retrieve git remote branches?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-remote, git-checkout

I'm clearly missing something since I am unable to fetch the remote branch I need on the server from the git repo I've been working with locally.

**On my local dev environment**

I run `git remote -v` and it gives me:

```
origin  git@git.example.com:the_repo (fetch)
origin  git@git.example.com:the_repo (push)
```

I run `git branch` and it gives me:

```
* live
  master
```

**On my live server environment**

I run `git remote -v` and it gives me:

```
origin  git@git.example.com:the_repo (fetch)
origin  git@git.example.com:the_repo (push)
```

I run `git branch` and it gives me:

```
* master
```

When I try to fix this situation by running `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`, I still do not see my `live` branch upon running `git branch` again. I suspect this is because `git branch` only lists my local branches.

**How can I fetch the repo's remote branches and list them before I check them out locally?**

Many thanks - much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command `git branch -r` to see remote branches.

Answer (score 2):

Matt's answer is correct, but just to add:

```
git branch -a
```

will display "all" branches, both local and remote.

Answer (score 0):

Matt and CodingWithSpike's responses both work for my purposes (thanks). Additionally, I've just found that the `git branch -vv` command displays which local branches are associated with which remote branches.